# Problems when installing 'Ubuntu After Install'

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, updates, ppa

I have problems after installing Ubuntu 16.10, upgraded and reinstalled it after having lots of bugs and who knows what on my laptop. I'm just guessing when  I'm trying to work things out, so probably have only made things worse. I'm following [Top 37 things to do after installing Ubuntu 16.10 (Yakkety Yak) to make as user friendly](http://www.2daygeek.com/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-16-10/4/), thinking that things will get sorted... anyway, I tried to install this [Brand New App – Ubuntu After Install (Hassle Free Software installation)](http://www.2daygeek.com/tips-for-ubuntu-after-install-hassle-free-software-installation/) after I have done "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thefanclub/ubuntu-after-install" and update I get this error msg:

```
W: The repository 'http:  //ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/ubuntu-after-install/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/thefanclub-ubuntu-ubuntu-after-install-yakkety.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/thefanclub-ubuntu-ubuntu-after-install-yakkety.list:3
E: Failed to fetch http: //ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/ubuntu-after-install/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/thefanclub-ubuntu-ubuntu-after-install-yakkety.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/thefanclub-ubuntu-ubuntu-after-install-yakkety.list:3
```

Well I think I stop there and see if I can get someone that would like to help me out. I just am so confused, and keep trying things, which is completely stupid I guess!! :(

Many Thanks for any help!!

Comment: OK! I have un-ticked everything in Other Software. Updated, and the install is going fine now!